# column _id does not exist - but i am sure it does

Tags: java, android, database

In a previous question I posted (which contains all the code)

[Unable to substantiate activity ComponentInfo - Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9706253/1096365)

I had a nullexception error, howver having beaten that runtime error, i have tripped over another. the log cat is:

```
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.dbtest/com.android.dbtest.ShowActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1622)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:111)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:90)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:47)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:84)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at com.android.dbtest.ShowActivity.onCreate(ShowActivity.java:45)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
03-14 17:43:25.169: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(339):     ... 11 more
```

this problem occurs once the Show button has been pressed and the ShowActivity is launched (the answer to the above link regarding where to init the listcontent has been implemented) - however, it now seems to be failing due to the colum _id. Which as far as i can see is initilised in my adapter.

Any help , greatfully received.

EDIT: Added the following code - and addign comment below

```
package com.android.dbtest;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class AddActivity extends DatabaseTestActivity{

private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
private String jobId;

SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
Cursor cursor;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final EditText jobIdInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.jobText); 
    //final EditText address1Input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add1Text);  to be implemented

    /**************************************************
     * 
     *  Get text Input from Edit Text Fields
     * 
     ***************************************************/

    jobIdInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable id) {
            jobId = jobIdInput.getText().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    /***************************************************
     * 
     *  initialise Database
     * 
     * 
     ***************************************************/
    mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);

    /*****************************************************
     * Listen for Confirm button press
     ******************************************************/

    final Button confirm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.confirmButt);

    confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
            mySQLiteAdapter.insert(jobId);
            mySQLiteAdapter.close();
        }

    });

    /***********************************************************
     * write jobId into SQl in the above method for button press
     * 
     *************************************************************/     
}
}
```

Comment: Try bumping up your DB version number. If you didn't have _id in version 1 and then added in _id later your DB will not reflect this until your version # is incremented.

Comment: So do you create an _id column in your CREATE TABlE statement (usually done somewhere in onCreateDatabase() in SQLiteHelper-derived class I believe)

Comment: @dymmeh - i tried updated the version, no joy, thanks all the same.

Comment: @Alex - i think i have created the table with the column, it can be seen via the link at the top of my post.

Comment: @CornishDibley - have you tried uninstalling your application, placing a break point on the line db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE); in your SQLiteHelper class and running it in debug mode to make sure it gets executed? Make sure to debug it the first time you run it. Creating the DB will only occur the first time you run your application (unless the DB version # is incremented) so if you try to debug it on the 2nd run you won't hit that breakpoint. Thats why I say to uninstall it first :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work out the answer; from the fact that the database was not actually being created. Was not effected by version changes, moreover what the solution was was to initalise the database in the Main DatabaseTestActivity NOT the AddActivty!!

Of course no  i have smacked right into another NullPointerException - but at least it is a different problem to deal with now!!

Answer (score 0):

As @CornishDibley have said, I think you need to delete your database from you phone/emulator.
As far as I know, there are two ways to do that:

1. Go to manage applications >> choose your app >> hit clear data
2. Simply uninstall your app as @CornishDibley have said

This should solve your version problem

Hint: Put tracing logs to debug your program and trace every function that gets exectuted. See if you onCreat is executing. If not, your old database file is still there (as far as I know)

Comment: I Have Added some additional text for my AddActivity (actions when the add button pressed) - reading what has been said and importantly following the tags, i think i have managed to narrow down that the onCreate of the DB is not being called - am i maybe right in thinking this? however i thought 'mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);' did exactly that - however my break point and log in the oncreate are not being triggered!

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what we have anticipated. Have you uninstalled the app from your phone or emulator "manually"?

Comment: Hi G Nag - Yes i have uninstalled it from my phone. I also put a Log.v at the OnCreate() and nothign is recorded in my log. Also, I have tried looking direct at the DB via sqlite3 and is seems to indicate that i dont have a datbase call MY_DATABASE - I am thinkign that it just is not beign created at all!